# Prove bijection between two ordered fields with least upper bound property is an order-isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

I have a map $f\colon F_1\to F_2$ defined by $f=\alpha_1\circ\beta_1$ where

> $\beta_1\colon F_1\to DC, \beta_1(f) = \{ q\in\mathbb{Q} \mid i_1(q) < f \}$
> where $i_1$ is the unique injective map from $\mathbb{Q}\to F_1$ which preserves +, $\cdot$ , < $\alpha_2\colon DC\to F_2, \alpha_2(S) = \sup S$.

I know $f$ is a bijection, but how do I show it respects $+$, $\cdot$ , and <?

For example to show $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$ I have

$\beta_1(a+b) = \{ q\in\mathbb{Q} \mid i_1(q) < a+b \}$.

But how would I find the supremum of this in $F_2$? I'm not quite sure since the Dedekind cut is "represented" by elements of $F_1$. Furthermore I think I have to apply $\sup (A+B) = \sup A+ \sup B$ but I'm not sure during which step it is appropriate to state that.

I think I know how to do this from between the reals and an a ordered field with LUBP but when it's $F_1$ and $F_2$ I get a little confused on how to relate things in the different sets.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to prove $$\beta_1(a+b)=\beta_1(a)+\beta_1(b).$$ Here I mean addition of sets on the rhs.

Comment: I think I've proved this in class, when extended the set of Dedekind cuts to an ordered field with LUBP and defined the + operator pretty much like that. However I do think I see the intuition now, if we know the equality you stated, then $f(a+b) = \sup\beta_1(a+b) = \sup(\beta_1(a)+\beta_1(b))$ and then I use the property which allows me to "distribute" the supremum and finally rewrite as $f(a)+f(b)$, right?

Comment: Also, if you think you know how to do it for the reals, I'd suggest spelling out the details and afterwards check what properties of the reals you have used.